# Getting "Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/" exception Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am trying to share a screenshot of my activity.

I am creating a bitmap like this

```
fun createImageToShare(): Bitmap {
        val b =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(
                recyclerViewGroups.getWidth(),
                recyclerViewGroups.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
        val c = Canvas(b)
        recyclerViewGroups.draw(c)
        return b
    }
```

Then I am trying to save the bitmap to a file like this

```
fun saveBitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap): File? {
        try {
            val dir = File(this.cacheDir,"myfolder").apply { mkdirs() }
            val fileName = "myfile.jpg"
            val file = File(
                dir,
                fileName
            )
            println("file path ${file.path}")
            val fOut = FileOutputStream(file)


            bitmap.compress(
                Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                85,
                fOut
            ) 
            fOut.close()
            return file
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
```

Then I am trying to share this file using SHARE_INTENT like this

```
R.id.menu_share -> {
                try {
                    val bmp = createImageToShare()
                    val str = saveBitmapToFile(bmp)
                    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.mypackage.myrepo.fileprovider",str!!)
                    println("URI PATH $uri")
                    val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                        type = "image/jpeg"
                    }
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to"))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
```

I have `Permissions` and `Provider` like this on my Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Inside the `Application` tag

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mypackage.myrepo.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This is the content of my `file_paths`

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path
        name="myrepo"
        path="myfolder/" />
    <external-files-path
        name="myrepo"
        path="myfolder/"/>
</paths>
```

So when I try to share this image, the file path printed is

```
file path /data/user/0/com.mypackage.myrepo/cache/myfolder/myfile.jpg
```

and the exception I get is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.mypackage.myrepo/cache/myfolder/myfile.jpg
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at com.mypackage.myrepo.group.GroupActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(GroupActivity.kt:109)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3543)
```

I just want to share an image of my activity. The file location can be internal or external but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, that all looks correct, at first glance. Had you modified `file_paths` to add the `<cache-path>` after having built previously? Did you try cleaning/rebuilding, or even Invalidate Caches/Restart?

Comment: @MikeM. tried everything still the same error